# Email Verification with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, mailgun

I am using Mailgun to send my emails from WordPress, I always have this on the logs

```
 Failed: wordpress@52fluent.com → webmaster@52fluent.com 'Mailgun WordPress Plugin Test' Server response: 550 Verification failed for <bounce+dd882b.7933e-webmaster=52fluent.com@52fluent.com> No Such User Here" Sender verify failed
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailgun uses specially formatted Return-Path address to track bounces. But if you use a different service to receive emails this address is not valid until exists on the server and accepts address tags (bounce+something@example.com).

Some info on how Mailgun handle bounces [How can the Return-Path header be different than the actual email bounce recipient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615229/how-can-the-return-path-header-be-different-than-the-actual-email-bounce-recipie)

UPDATE: Here is response from Mailgun support

> The reason the error messages is due to Sender Address Verification or also known as Callback Verification (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_verification). Mailgun rewrites the return-path tracking soft-bounce. When the recipient tries verify the address return path address, it's not able to verify and causes the error, "No Such User Here" Sender verify failed" There are several solutions to resolve this :
>
> Disable sender verification from the server. (This would require access to the server to disable the configuration.)
>
> The MX records can be pointed to Mailgun for us to verify the address and use a sub-domain to forward the message back to the local server.
>
> Setup the domain authority to resolve to mailgun.org. The down side to this will be "via Mailgun" when sending to Gmail addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup in Mailgun for each FROM account, do this inner domain section (of mailgun) and then in SMTP credentials, where you will add your login/from account and the password for that account.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the e-mail webmaster@52fluent.com address isn't actually setup yet.  Is this an actual working e-mail address setup at your host?

Comment: it is a forwarder email, that passes emails to another email

Comment: I believe you have to set it as a "real" email to have this work.  Even if that mail is then still forwarded.  It's a distinction in how you set it up with your host in your CP.