# Migrating from Mandrill to Mailgun in Laravel - Server response: 550

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun, email-forwarding

I have migrated from Mandrill to Mailgun in Laravel.

Everything is working fine, with one exception, if the recipient of the message is a **forwarder**, Mailgun returns the following error:

`550 Verification failed for <bounce+7d2e9f.239f3-address=mydomain.com@mydomain.com>\nNo Such User Here\"\nSender verify failed`

The domain in question has all DNS settings checked in green at my Mailgun dashboard.

I'm not being able to find relevant information about this specific situation with Mailgun, and since a huge migration from Mandrill to Mailgun is happening right now, I hope someone has already tackled this problem.

Comment: [You should find your answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21841966/1206267). I don't normally just post links, but I'm pretty sure that's exactly what you need.